# Oracle TDE with java encryption

Tags: java, oracle, encryption, tde

We have an application consisting of customer mobile's number , which we are encrypting using our own key and storing in database. But now we are suggested to use **ORACLE KEY VAULT** for managing key. I would like to know, how the key will be generated now , and how those keys will be used in my java code to encrypt the data.

Any small help is also appreciable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including a minimal example of the code you are currently using and the changes you are making for the Oracle Key Vault.

Comment: Why not ask Oracle or your local representative? I don't think SO is the right place to ask for sample code / documentation of such products. It seems to handle Java key stores, so I guess that Java applications will have to rely on those.